# select box making sticky when generating it from an array

Tags: php, html

I am using this array to make a select box. Its ok. Its working for me. But I need to make this select box sticky that mean I need to HTML form that remembers how I filled it
out.

I add this code in foreach loop. but its not working..

```
// Check for stickyness:
if ( $_POST['how_hear'] == $value){
  echo " selected='selected'";
}
```

This is my whole code

```
$howHear = array( 1 =>  'option value 01', 
                        'option value 02', 
                        'option value 03', 
                        'option value 04', 
                        'option value 05', 
                        'option value 06', 
                        'option value 07', 
                        'option value 08'
                    );

echo "<select name='how_hear'>
        <option>--Select an Option--</option>\n";

    foreach ( $howHear AS $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value='{$key}'";

        // Check for stickyness:
        if ( $_POST['how_hear'] == $value){
            echo " selected='selected'";
        }
        echo ">$value</option>\n";
    }
echo "</select>\n";
```

hope someone will help me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `$_POST['how_hear']` to the *key*, not the value.  It's the key (value attribute in `<option>` that's being submitted with the form).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing your `$_POST['how_hear']` to the value of the select list not the key. Try:

```
// Check for stickyness:
if ( $_POST['how_hear'] == $key){
    echo " selected='selected'";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well  remember you are passing the "key" as the actual HTML value in the form so technically `$_POST['how_hear']` contains a key and not a $value. Just change `if ( $_POST['how_hear'] == $key){` and it should work, assuming the rest of your code is ok...